# find ahref value based on attribute using jquery

Tags: jquery, html

I am trying to find aherf value when there is an active attribute in the list which ahref belongs to

```
<ul class="nav nav-tabs " id="segmentTabs" role="tablist">
  <li class="nav-item active">
    <a class="nav-link" id="segment-tab" data-toggle="tab" href="#segment" role="tab" aria-controls="#engagement" aria-selected="false" data-value="segments"></a>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Here is what I tried with jQuery. I get `undefined` in `value`.

```
var $segmentTabs = $('#segmentTabs');

function exportClientCharts() {
  var $controlButtons = $segmentTabs.find('.active');
  var value = $controlButtons.data('value');
  if (value === Enums.dashboardTabs.SEGMENTS) {
    SegmentCountsChart.exportClientCharts();
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$controlButtons.find('a').attr('href');
```

Comment: `$controlButtons` is a jQuery object already, no need to wrap it in `$()`.

Answer (score 0):

The `data-value` is on the `a` within the `li.active`, so you need to change your selector in `find()`:

```js
var $segmentTabs = $('#segmentTabs');

function exportClientCharts() {
  var $controlButtons = $segmentTabs.find('.active a'); // note the addition of 'a' here
  var value = $controlButtons.data('value');

  if (value === Enums.dashboardTabs.SEGMENTS) {
    SegmentCountsChart.exportClientCharts();
  }
}
```